# how to interactively toggle CSS sheets(s) on a webpage for testing/learning purposes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for different approaches that can accomodate toggling all, or select style sheets  present on a webpage, without having to comment multi lines of code, since nesting comments is not allowed in CSS.

Background:
I am trying to learn the different effects of different css sheets, and would like the interaction to be WYSIWYG for non devs.   Currently, the only thing I have [found](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/4087.htm) is this:

```
<a href="javascript:var%20i=0;if(document.styleSheets.length>0)
{cs=!document.styleSheets[0].disabled;
    for(i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++)
        %20document.styleSheets[i].disabled=cs;};
    void(cs=true);">Toggle stylesheet</a>
```

I am open to HTML, JS, Java, JQuery, or CSS implementations.

*CLARIFICATION* - Can style sheets be selected using JQuery?, as this would seem possible if  they could be selected.

For those that keep closing this post, how about giving me some feedback so I can accomodate your needs, instead of just closing the post.   In case you din't know, when you close it, it sends me to  FAQ page, not your feedback, and I don't know what to change.   Also, There are other people that are answering, according to my notifications, but by the time i get back to the post, I can't see it since its closed, and the notifications only include the first few words, so they aren't helpful.

Comment: Just a guess but, inject stylesheet tags into the head of the DOM?

Comment: Everyone of these answers below require you to use an inspector to turn on or off sheets - you want this to be a live, interactive method where users toggle stylesheets based on some conditions, correct?

Comment: correct, so that users, who are not necessarily comfortable/familiar with the console/addons/extras/etc could visualize the direct effects of css of static HTML.   I would not be opposed to extensions that can  self intall with ease, that would enable this functionality either.   The hope is that a new dev/user could thematically choose the display of the content, but also see which CSS is in effect, thus allowing for comparison, a notable form of top down non conventional learning.

Comment: @Mike, could you clarify a bit more please?

Comment: see my answer below for further clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) is great for toggling CSS styles, or even adding styles, all while viewing the changes live on your page.

To use, open your page in Chrome, right-click on the part of the page you want to check out, and choose "Inspect Element".

Comment: I currently use this, and I didn't know i could toggle individual sheets.   Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [Firefox Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/). There is a CSS menu that lets you disable & re-enable individual stylesheets. I believe that this add-on is also available for Chrome. It also lets you live edit the CSS. It has a bunch of great tools for web developers.

Comment: It's not even an add-on anymore, it's been built directly into the past few versions of Firefox. `Inspect` and `Scratchpad` are the menu items I like the most, and coincidentally are the ones I've used the most.

Answer (score 2):

I use Firefox as my "main" browser, and the absolutely brilliant Firebug plugin will allow you to toggle stylesheets or specific CSS properties within those stylesheets.

[Read more about Firebug CSS handling here](http://getfirebug.com/css)

Comment: You don't even need Firebug anymore now that Firefox has those web developer tools built-in. Though there are some differences in the way they work, so some people might still prefer how Firebug does things.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something along these lines:
http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/

Something that can, when clicked switch the `href=""` of a `<link>` tag out with a different stylesheet the link above will do exactly as mentioned.

Comment: thankyou!  All the other answers on to this question are about using browser tools, which is fine and probably answers the question... but with this option, non-technical site visitors can select a style from within the page itself, or the page could automatically switch to night/day styles based upon browsers' local time.

Answer (score 1):

Were you aware that most modern browsers have a "Page Style" menu item that lets you select the active stylesheet for a page from a list of stylesheets provided by the page author? In Firefox it's `View > Page Style`. Not sure what it is in Chrome or IE9, but it shouldn't be hard to find in those.